# extract a value from a pandas dataframe dict into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df.head(10)

```
    XYZVal
0   {"X":"56.68","Y":"51.56","Z":"100"}
1   {"X":"58.05","Y":"52.37","Z":"62.6"}
2   {"X":"59.32","Y":"54.48","Z":"69.59"}
3   {"X":"58.51","Y":"36.36","Z":"82.76"}
4   {"X":"65.21","Y":"60.26","Z":"71.06"}
5   {"X":"57.64","Y":"52.07","Z":"67.89"}
6   {"X":"58.24","Y":"50","Z":"75"}
7   {"X":"57.69","Y":"52.13","Z":"68.64"}
8   {"X":"57.83","Y":"53.05","Z":"65.92"}
9   {"X":"60.87","Y":"51.73","Z":"71.35"}
```

How to convert the above dataframe into a new dataframe by selecting X:

```
{ 56.68 ,58.05 ,59.32 ,58.51 ,65.21 ,57.64 ,58.24 ,57.69 ,57.83 ,60.87 }
```

df.info()
shows

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 1 columns):
XYZVal    100 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
```

Comment: Is df a list of dictionaries?  What object is df?

Comment: Please provide more information. Right now, we can't tell what df is.

Comment: I edited you question to reference pandas.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question with output of info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `XYZVal` does already contain dicts, just use:

```
df.XYZVal.apply(lambda x: x["X"])
```

If the column entries are strings, just use:

```
import json
df['XYZVal'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x)["X"])
```

result (in both ways)

```
0    56.68
1    58.05
2    59.32
3    58.51
4    65.21
5    57.64
6    58.24
7    57.69
8    57.83
9    60.87
Name: XYZVal, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
df_list = df['XYZVal'].to_list()

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
X_df = new_df['X']
```

Comment: Thanks. But it gives error KeyError: 'X' when doing new_df['X']